# jQuery type class structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

So I was wondering if anyone could help me understand how the jQuery 'class' works. From what I can tell, it works like a static class like such:

```
if(!$) { var $ = new function(){} }
```

I think..

Now, what is confusing to me, is how you can call a method both with OR without arguments like such:

```
$("a").removeClass("test");
$.get('myhtmlpage.html', myCallBack);
```

I am assuming passing that argument simply returns `document.getElementById(argument);`

But how? How is this argument passed into the class after the fact like this? also, is this some result of method chaining?

Anything info to help me understand what is going on would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working with the jQuery source here, so you can look at it as well.

The `$` function isn't explicitly defined, but instead linked to the `jQuery` object:

```
window.$ = jQuery;
```

The `jQuery` object is defined like so:

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
    constructor: jQuery,
    init: function( selector, context, rootjQuery ) {
```

The `init: function( selector` part handles `$('foo')` cases.

If no parameters are given, the another function is used:

```
get: function( num ) {
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Anymore info would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Variables in JavaScript can contain $. for example foo and $foo are different variables. Naturally $ is a valid object.

Next thing worth noting is that in JavaScript everything is a class. Function is a class too, so your function might have methods too.

$ <-- this is a function with methods.

$('a') <-- this executes that function which does something and return $ again.

$.get() <-- this calls method of that jQuery function.

$('a').get() <-- this executes function with argument a which returns $ again then you grab it's method and execute that again.

When $('a') is called, not the exact same $ is returned, it would contain some extra information about the selector you used.

My final note is that when you call $(x); where x is a function, then it's used as a shortcut to registering on-document-ready call-back.